# JCheckBox: showMessageDialog twice in ItemStateChanged event

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Why is my program calling `showMessageDialog` twice in `ItemStateChanged` event, even I put it in if else?

```
private void checkBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                           
    if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        //System.out.println("Check box 1 selected");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check box 1 selected");
    }
    else{
        //System.out.println("Check box 1 deselected");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check box 1 deselected");
    }
}
```

If I only use `System.out.println`, the program will run correctly.

Comment: Maybe there's more than one thread that access this code.

Comment: I have created new JFrame Form and there is anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the checkbox is not being updated before the JOptionPane is displayed. (Notice how the checkmark is not painted when the first option pane is displayed.

So what you need to do is make sure the state is updated and repainted before displaying the JOption pane by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) to display the JOptionPane:

```
checkBox.addItemListener( new ItemListener()
{
    public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check box 1 selected");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check box 1 deselected");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I am a beginer so it's very difficult to understand@@ I will learn more about SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...), thread,... before try to fix my problem with your advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tmd, `I will learn more about SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...),` - start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understand more about the `Event Dispatch Thread`.

Comment: Thank you for everything. But I can't accept your answer because I don't ensure your answer is correct. But if anyone ensures that your answer correctly, I will do it.

Comment: @TMD, of course you can accept the answer. It solves your problem. That is the point of the forum to give solutions to problems. There is never a single correct answer. Problems can be solved in many ways. If somebody posts what you think is a better solution then you can always change the accepted answer.